# golang :how do I handle index out of range error?

Tags: go, panic

I am writing a CLI interface program in Go.my program requires a user to enter  a filename as an argument . following is the code I wrote to handle 
the situations in which user doesn't enter any argument . but it panics and gives an error "index out of range".how do I handle this?

```
  package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("usage: gohex  <filename>")

        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        filename := os.Args[1]

        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(hex.Dump(data))
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show us the complete code. The current snippet cannot panic.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Are you sure you get this error on exactly this code?

Comment: In Go as in C, the executable path is passed as first parameter of the arguments list. So you have to check that len == 1

Comment: @Warrior can you elaborate please?

Comment: When you run your program the minimum length of `os.Args` is 1 because by default the first position is occupied by the executable (your program) path. If the user inserts one or more parameters you have `len(os.Args)` > 1 so use that as condition to see if there are additional commandline arguments (or `len(os.Args) == 1` in your case).

Comment: Args will always be at least 1 long, because Args[0] will be the executable's name. So your first if check for len == 0 is failing.

Comment: oh ok .i got that .thank you @Warrior

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem relies in this line:

```
if len(os.Args) == 0
```

You are checking for the first argument which as you supposed should be the filename, but in fact is the go / executable filename. So if you wish to check if an argument has been provided you need to check that the argument length is greater than `1`. Change the code to:

```
if len(os.Args) <= 1 {
    log.Fatal("usage: gohex  <filename>")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answer has a couple of issues. It has this check:

```
len(os.Args) <= 1
```

but `len(os.Args)` must always be at least `1`, so using `<=` is pointless.
Further, in this specific case, `len` of anything other than `2` is invalid as
well. So just check that:

```
package main
import "os"

func main() {
   if len(os.Args) != 2 {
      println("gohex <filename>")
      return
   }
   filename := os.Args[1]
   println(filename)
}
```

Side note, personally I also think using `os.Exit(1)` is invalid in this context
as well. I think "printing the help text" is a valid use case, and not an error.